# MYSQL: Converting a double column to integer

Tags: mysql

I have a column of 105 million values that are either: `0.001, 0.002, 0.01, 0.02` and I am finding that the querying time is very long. So I would like to convert that column to an integer (e.g. `1,2,3,4` based on the above). Is it possible to do within MYSQL?

Comment: Does 1 map to 0.01 or 0.001? And can you confirm if it is a double and not a decimal column?

Comment: I'm querying it from R so I can only see that it says <dbl> unfortunately. In terms of mapping `0.001, 0.002, 0.01, 0.02` maps to `1, 2, 3, 4`. Purely based on ascending magnitude.

Comment: *In terms of mapping `0.001, 0.002, 0.01, 0.02` maps to `1, 2, 3, 4`* If 0.005 will be inserted in future, what value it will be mapped onto?

Comment: Good question! No values will be inserted later, this is the final table.

Comment: Whichever way, four distinct values spread over 105 million rows is very likely to lead to the entire index (or table) being read, if filtering on that column.  Using an integer will certainly reduce the total amount (in bytes) of data read though.

Comment: @WillA when I exclude this column in the query, it's pretty fast, but when I query it with abs(nameCol - 0.001)<1e-15 for example it takes minutes, sorry R syntax but you get the gist. So I think this is the bottleneck for sure.

Comment: Could you instead try nameCol < 0.0011, does that perform as badly?

Comment: @WillA It won't query it at all using that. I don't really know why

Comment: *No values will be inserted later, this is the final table.* `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column)`.

Comment: *and I am finding that the querying time is very long.* Maybe you need in proper indexing simply? Provide: precise MySQL version, precise table's CREATE TABLE, full text for problematic query and its EXPLAIN. In theory your "mapping" shouldn't improve performance.

Comment: @Akina thank you. could you please explain what `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column)` does?

Comment: *what `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column)` does?* It calculates the number of row in the rowset under specified ordering. I.e. it enumerates the rows. And it is the mapping which you need. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=45aba0d71ca6e6329ba74c6b13776ba1

Comment: PS. I think that the partitioning may be more suitable solution.

Comment: Ohhh Interesting, thank you very much. I'm going to look into partitioning. I wonder how much speed improvements it would bring?